# Java Thread problem - updating GUI

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to use threads to run a lenghty operation in the background and update the UI.
Here's what i'm trying to do:

1. on a button click, display a popupjframe with a message "Inserting into DB"
2. create a new thread to insert 1000s of entries into a database.
3. when the entries are inserted, i want the popupjframe to disappear and display a joptionpane with yes, no buttons
4. on clicking the yes button i want to display another frame with a report/details about the insertion process

Here's my code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
//display popupframe first

jFrame1.pack();
jFrame1.setVisible(true);
jFrame1.setLocationRelativeTo(getFrame());
Thread queryThread = new Thread() {
public void run() {
runQueries();
}};
queryThread.start();
}
```

`//runqueries method inserts into DB`

```
private void runQueries() {
for (int i = 0; i <= 50000; i++) {
insertintoDB();
updateProgress(i);
}
}

//update the popupjframe
private void updateProgress(final int queryNo) {
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
if (queryNo == 50000) { //means insertion is done
jFrame1.setVisible(false);

int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(getFrame(), menuBar, null, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

if (n == 1) { //NO option was selected
return;}
else
//display another popupframe with details/report of inserting process
}});
}
```

1. Is my approach correct??
2. **How and when** do i stop/interrupt the "queryThread"??
3. Is it correct if i make the popupjframe in the runqueries method itself (after the for loop) and  display the joptionpane??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your runQueries() method, you are calling updateProgress() 50000 times, each time creating a new thread, whereas only the last one needs to do any useful work. It may not be heavy, but it is unnecessary overhead, and misleading code at best. And ILMTitan is correct: SwingWorker is the proper way to go here.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the documentation for [SwingWorker](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). It does exactly what you are trying to do. Create a subclass, and call runQueries from doInBackground(), and then do what your runnable does (minus the if queryNo check) in done(). There are third party versions of this class if you are not using java 1.6.

```
class DbSwingWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 50000; i++) {
            insertintoDB();
            publish(i); //if you want to do some sort of progress update
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(getFrame(), menuBar, null, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        if (n == 1) { //NO option was selected
            return;
        } else {
            //display another popupframe with details/report of inserting process

        }
    }
}
```

The original, non-1.6 version can be found here: https://swingworker.dev.java.net/

Comment: Also see <http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html>.